# Ruby metaprogramming, how does RSpec's 'should' work?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, rspec

I was reading up on RSpec and I was trying to figure out how RSpec's "should" was implemented.

Could someone give a hand on how the meta nature of this function works?

The code is located here:

http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/expectations/extensions/kernel.rb

TIA,

-daniel

Clarification:

```
target.should == 5
```

How did target's value get passed along to "should", which in turn was "=="'d against 5?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at [class OperatorMatcher](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/matchers/operator_matcher.rb).

It all boils down to Ruby allowing you to leave out periods and parenthesis.  What you are really writing is:

```
target.should.send(:==, 5)
```

That is, send the message `should` to the object `target`, then send the message `==` to whatever `should` returns.

The method `should` is monkey patched into `Kernel`, so it can be received by any object.  The `Matcher` returned by `should` holds the `actual` which in this case is `target`.

The `Matcher` implements the method `==` which does the comparison with the `expected` which, in this case, is the number 5.  A cut down example that you can try yourself:

```
module Kernel
  def should
    Matcher.new(self)
  end
end

class Matcher
  def initialize(actual)
    @actual = actual
  end

  def == expected
    if @actual == expected
      puts "Hurrah!"
    else
      puts "Booo!"
    end
  end
end

target = 4
target.should == 5
=> Booo!

target = 5
target.should == 5
=> Hurrah!
```

Comment: Thanks fo a great little explanation that not only answers the question but is a nice summary of some mechanisms in Ruby. For people new to Ruby, be aware that the last expression in a function is implicitly the return value, so should above would in C++ be 
Matcher* Kernel::should()
{
  return new Matcher(this);
}

Comment: First: Very good answer, thanks a lot! Two quick observations: instead  of defining "should" on the Kernel module, you could do it on the class Object. I find it safer, as it's less generic. The second thing is that you don't need metaprogramming to define the method ==. You can just define it as any other normal method, so that it's easier to read: def ==(expected)

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas, I have updated my answer with your suggestion.