# What exactly is the keyword "should" in RSpec Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am a beginner in Ruby and had this question nagging me for a long time.

In an RSpec file , if we write `Book.should <do something>` , what is the `should` keyword? Is it a member of the Book object? How did it come to be the member of the Book object? Or is it some construct of Ruby? Is it a function? Where can i find the definition of this if it is a function or member?

Comment: This question is the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105755/ruby-metaprogramming-how-does-rspecs-should-work

Comment: The link does not explain what it actually does. What exactly is the keyword "should"?

Comment: +1 for trying to understand the magic.

Comment: @MIkhail I'd love to know what I could add to the linked answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3114610/104219) to help explain.  I tried to provide a cut down example of the original RSpec code that is linked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upon loading, RSpec includes [a module](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/blob/master/lib/spec/expectations/extensions/kernel.rb) into the `Kernel` module which is included into all objects known to Ruby. Thus, it can make the should method available to all objects. As such, `should` is not a keyword (like `if`, `class`, or `end`) but an ordinary method.

Note that that mixin is only available in RSpec contexts as it is "patched in" during loading or RSpec.

Answer (score 3):

I've answered a similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883688/586748). Basically:

What I think Holger's answer could make more explicit, and what may be what initially confused you, is that `should` breaks most of the usual conventions for method naming (nothing about the method describes what it does, for example) in order to make the code as a whole read as a sort of sentence.

So rather than just creating a set of tests, the library is trying to encourage you to describe your application through tests in a way that resembles a human-readable specification.

Comment: Creates an assertion that a condition is true that will run as part of your test. So it's similar to saying `assert x == y`.